# Why BIOS need to compare a value in (seemly) randomized address to zero in the second instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, qemu, bios, osdev

I am trying to learn operating system by diving into the low-level details of it. And the course I'm now on is [MIT 6.828 Operating System Engineering](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2018/schedule.html). The lab asks students to trace into the BIOS for a few instructions. The first three assembly instructions of BIOS list as folllows:

```
0xffff0:    ljmp    $0xf000,$0xe05b
0xfe05b:    cmpl    $0x0,%cs:0x6c48
0xfe062:    jne     0xfd2e1
```

What I can't figure out is the second one: `cmpl    $0x0,%cs:0x6c48` . What does it do? Why need this condition before `jmp` to a specific place? I have searched on the web for a while, but still can't find an explanation. And what's trickier is that I find different people get different addresses to compare to, like `0x6ac8`, `0x65a4` or `0x6c48` here.

Comment: I suppose that's an implementation detail of your BIOS.  It likely checks if this is a normal reset or a reset that is part of the BIOS initialisation routine, allowing the BIOS to get back to where it was before the reset.  Since each BIOS does this in its own way, the address is going to be different on each BIOS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What exactly that comparison does will depend on the BIOS manufacturer, but it is clearly some flag for [POST (Power on Self Test)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test) processing. Some BIOSes may have completely different code that doesn't look anything like those instructions. Since you are using QEMU, the default BIOS being used is [SeaBIOS](https://www.seabios.org/SeaBIOS). That `cmpl` is to determine if a [reboot or a resume](https://www.seabios.org/Execution_and_code_flow#Resume_and_reboot) is being done:

> As noted above, on emulators SeaBIOS handles the 0xFFFF0000:FFF0 machine startup execution vector. This vector is also called on machine faults and on some machine "resume" events. It can also be called (as 0xF0000:FFF0) by software as a request to reboot the machine (on emulators, coreboot, and CSM).
>
> The SeaBIOS "resume and reboot" code handles these calls and attempts to determine the desired action of the caller. Code flow starts in 16bit mode in romlayout.S:reset_vector() which calls romlayout.S:entry_post() which calls romlayout.S:entry_resume() which calls resume.c:handle_resume(). Depending on the request the handle_resume() code may transition to 32bit mode.

You can look at the [source code](https://github.com/coreboot/seabios/blob/master/src/romlayout.S) for the SeaBIOS for the `entry_post` code which is where the `jmp    $0xf000,$0xe05b` takes you:  .

```
        ORG 0xe05b
entry_post:
        cmpl $0, %cs:HaveRunPost                // Check for resume/reboot
        jnz entry_resume
        ENTRY_INTO32 _cfunc32flat_handle_post   // Normal entry point
```

If the 32-bit value at `%cs:HaveRunPost` is not zero then it is a resume operation, otherwise it is a reboot operation. The address of `HaveRunPost` or any internal BIOS variables may differ between one version of a SeaBIOS to another. This may because of changes to code between versions; compiler/compiler options used to build the ROM; BIOS features chosen etc.

Comment: Now the question is how is this value is supposed to change, given that it's located in ROM.

Comment: @RossRidge : SeaBIOS temporarily makes the shadowed memory from 0xf0000 to 0x100000 writeable by changing the PAM settings through PCI configuration space (on intel)  which allows modification of the HaveRunPost memory location. SeaBIOS's  `make_bios_writable` function is used for that purpose as part of its shadow memory functionality.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks for your answer! But is this description right? "If the 32-bit value at %cs:HaveRunPost is not zero then it is a resume operation, otherwise it is a reboot operation." I mean, should the cases be classified into "resume/reboot" and "normal start" rather than "resume" and "reboot"?